# I cannot see the drives on my computer

Tags: drivers, hard-drive

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I installed this Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB stick. It all went fine but as I notice, there are no drives shown on the menu. I tried some command in the terminal to see if the drives are available and yes, they are available.

My problem is how to make these drives show up on the menu above. Sorry if this question is somewhat vague.

(I removed the image because I am not allowed to add an image because I have insufficient reputation)

Comment: what menu are you talking about? You can see your available drivers under software sources (`software-properties-gtk`) under the "Additional Drivers"-tab.

Comment: I think he meant drives not drivers? You can upload your screenshot at [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and post the link here.

Answer (score 1):

If you installation went successfully ...

The normal process is: Open home folder > Go > Computer. You should see all your drives.

If you still do not try install gparted and see if it picks it up.

(assuming you are not having an installation problem)